# Laravel relationships between 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, api, laravel, eloquent

Trying to figure out the following:

1. How to set up these tables.
2. The relationship between the tables using eloquent.

Essentially, you can create a post that is tied to a task. Each task can have unique details that would need the users input.

**Tables (one way of doing this)**

```
Schema::create('uniqueTopic1', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
$table->foreign('post_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('posts')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('uniqueDetails1');
$table->string('uniqueDetails2');
$table->string('uniqueDetails3');
$table->string('uniqueDetails4');
$table->string('uniqueDetails5');
$table->string('uniqueDetails6');
$table->string('title');
$table->string('description');
$table->string('mission');
$table->int('money');
$table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('uniqueTopic2', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('posts')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('uniqueDetails1');
    $table->string('uniqueDetails2');
    $table->string('uniqueDetails3');
    $table->int('level');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now I want to set this up in a way that I can grow this. As I add more tasks to the site I can dynamically grow that out. Thats why I am thinking of a posts table which references a Task Table which then can go into a details table for that specific task?

First of all is this the right way of setting this up?

Second of all what or how would i tie this together using eloquent? Many to many through? pivot table. This is for an API so its important to be able to build the JSON object ... this is not just getting passed to a view or something like that...

Comment: why do you want to have a separate table for each task?

Comment: I would end up with a bunch of NULLs if they were in the same table... and as the number of "tasks" (which i probably not the best name as an example) grows i would not want to have to change the table with all tasks in it. The details of a task are specific for a "task" or whatever you want to call it. How else would you design the tables?

Comment: you can achieve the same using key value pair, like param_name(varchar 128), param_value (varchar(128))

Answer (score 0):

**Database Scheme**

```php
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('sub_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->unsignedInteger('task_id');
    $table->foreign('task_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('tasks')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->unsignedInteger('task_id');
    $table->foreign('task_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('tasks')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Example Code**

```php
$task1 = Task::create(['title' => 'Market Shopping']);
$task2 = Task::create(['title' => 'Spring Cleaning']);

// Subtask for Task1
$task1->subTasks()->create([
    'title'       => 'Buy shampoo',
    'description' => 'Around 3 bottles will be good'
]);

$task1->subTasks()->create([
    'title'       => 'Buy donuts',
    'description' => 'I love the sprinkled ones!'
]);

// Subtask for Task2
$task2->subTasks()->create([
    'title'       => 'Recycle old bottles',
    'description' => 'They are in the garage'
]);

$task2->subTasks()->create([
    'title'       => 'Wash car',
    'description' => 'Do not forget the back seat'
]);
```

Comment: so only problem is that the sub tasks will have different inputs. Taking your example let me revise. 1 sec.

Comment: PHP is very goof at assuming variable types, you should have any issues: ("1" == 1) in PHP

Comment: check out the answer i gave below.

Comment: @Citti: what are you planning on doing when a *task3* comes around, create another table?

Comment: yea that is my thought. They will be custom fields anyways right? Is that not the way to approach it?

Comment: Not at all. The schema I posted is the way to go

Comment: You are missing a lot: the relationship between `tasks` and `sub_tasks` is one-to-many. Meaning one **Task** will have many **Sub-Tasks** and none of them will be null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111376/discussion-between-dov-benyomin-sohacheski-and-citti).

Answer (score -1):

@dov

so if i expanded on your idea i would end up with this then... no? Sorry it still is not clicking for me how i would make this work. apologies. I would end up with entries like:

DB entry for subtask 1 and sub task 2

```
1 | 1 | x | y | z | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | timestamps
2 | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | a | b | c | d | timestamps
```

Tables:

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('sub_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('task_id');
    $table->foreign('task_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('tasks')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('task1 specific input1');
    $table->string('task1 specific input2');
    $table->string('task1 specific input3');
    $table->string('task2 specific input1');
    $table->string('task2 specific input2');
    $table->string('task2 specific input3');
    $table->string('task2 specific input4');
    $table->string('task2 specific input5');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->unsignedInteger('task_id');
    $table->foreign('task_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('tasks')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating columns for inputs. Utilize relationships

Comment: sure i hear you a key/value setup. but how would i handle the differences between inputs... some details are boolean. Some are text. some are int. so how would i go about storing all those different details in that subtask table...